# WAMP not working anymore

Tags: windows, php, apache-http-server, localhost, wamp

I had been successfully using WAMP on my PC for a year or so **but after I got internet connection through LAN, I noticed that WAMP has stopped working.** When I go to http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 (port is set to 80), the page just keeps on loading indefinitely (of course there are no errors on the page, this is not related to any script errors).

**I tried:**

- Re-installing wamp
- Re-starting computer
- Checking to see if port 80 is used by some other program (none used that)
- I don't use SKype
- Saw server log of apache; nothing suspicious found
- Tried running on different browser

Also all services are running fine.

**What Works:**

- I can access MySQL successfully
- I can run PHP scripts inside an editor like PHP Designer 2005

Any ideas please, i have become very dejected, so please help.

**Details:**

Windows XP SP2 with Avira Antivirus

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the LAN interface and see if it's working?

Comment: Also, what is in your apache.conf?  Specifically, what is does the `Listen` line have on it?

Comment: @ o.k.w : yes still not working

Comment: @heavyd: localhost port 80

Answer (score 1):

- WAMP is fine.
- Disable LAN.
- Disable any chat and community program(steam and so on).
- Turn off antivirus.
- Working? No?
- Reinstall Windows or try to install wamp on your second partition.